# Custom Multiple Choice Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a custom multiple choice list view can any one please help.

In my case a have a custom layout with four text view and a checkbox.

this is my code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561814/1381622

---

this is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.take_order);

    addToOrder=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addToOrder);
    order=(Button)findViewById(R.id.order);
    back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
    buttonSeperator=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.buttonSeperator);

    spTable=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tableNo);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.tableList,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spTable.setAdapter(adapter);
    spTable.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    categoryList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.foodCategoryList);
    //categoryList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    //categoryList.setItemsCanFocus(false);




    fc=new FoodCategory();


    categoryAdapter=fc.new FoodAdapter(this,R.layout.food_category_list,fc.list);

    categoryList.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    fl=new FoodList();

    order.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    addToOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonSeperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        fl.bundleCategory=fc.list[position];
        fl.foodListService();

        WaiterFoodAdapter foodAdapter=new WaiterFoodAdapter(this, R.layout.take_order_list, fl.foodList);
        categoryList.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
        categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}
```

actually im using one list view and when user click on the list view i set another adapter within same list view...
and

```
public void back(View v)
{
    addToOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonSeperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    order.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    categoryList.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);       
}
```

when user click back button i again set the old adapter,,,,the second adapter listview cannot be clicked i dont know why??

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following link:

http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/18/listview-example-4-custom-layout-checkbox-imagebutton-textview/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are not acceptable here.